# Creating a pyqt5 text with a gradient color

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a gradient text. I found the way to create gradient backgrounds but not text.

Comment: While the solution proposed by mugiseyebrows could work for simple cases, it doesn't consider all aspects related to size, font and rich text related to QLabel. See my update on the question for which this was marked as duplicate, as you can use gradients in stylesheet (but you have to ensure that their syntax is correct).

Comment: I vote to reopen as the provided answer has only a QSS based solution (and wasn't correctly fixed until now) and there can be other possible solution using QPalette.

Comment: I Pasted the stylesheet. But the output text was only filled with one color, instead of gradient. Moreover, what do you mean by "it doesn't consider all aspects related to size, font and rich text related to QLabel"

Comment: *Where* did you paste *what* stylesheet? Please be precise! About the second question, QLabel has important features regarding size "hints" and policies that ensure that their text is always displayed. A comment is not a proper place to explain this, but consider the widget of the proposed solution: it doesn't consider its contents: you can resize it to a size smaller than the text, which is obviously not a good thing; and you cannot just set arbitrary minimum sizes, as you should consider the content, the alignment, possible word wrapping and, obviously, all aspects related to the font(s).

Comment: using PyQt's setStyleSheet Method. Okay, Now I understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: I pasted the stylesheet like this: mylabel.setStyleSheet("color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #fd3e7f)")

Comment: Please edit your post with a [mre]. Also check that the syntax is absolutely correct, as qgradient stylesheets are a bit picky and sometimes get ignored if the wrong character is out of place (for instance, you're missing a semicolon at the end of the stylesheet string).

Comment: Okay i will update the question with the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a pen with gradient as a brush

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 72)
        painter.setFont(font)
        rect = self.rect()
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(rect.topLeft(), rect.topRight())
        gradient.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.red)
        gradient.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.blue)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setBrush(gradient)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawText(QtCore.QRectF(rect), "Hello world", QtGui.QTextOption(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Its working as I want. But still, @musicamante gives a point.